# Remote desktop server as daemon

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, linux-mint, kde, kubuntu

I'm using KRFB as remote desktop server in my Linux Mint KDE. It works fine as usual remote desktop server but I've to log-in then run it manually (or at start up)

How can I run KRFB of any remoter desktop server runs as daemon without need to log-in at first?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to start a ssh session and run krfb:

local> $ ssh usuario equiporemoto
 usuario@equiporemoto > $ **krfb --display :0 &**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start a remote server that doesn't depend on the X-Server being started, you can add `su username -c remoteserver &` to /etc/rc.local. As KRFB depends on KDE or at least an X-Server running (didn't go to deep into it), you have to do a login on your machine.

The solution is enabling autologin for KDE and putting the remote server into KDEs autostart. As I'm not into KDE, I can't exactly tell you how you enable autologin and how autostart applications are set in KDE, but it shouldn't be much of a problem.